# DataTables Requested unknown parameter

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have looked through all the other answers here but could not find one that simply states a solution the the error I am having,

My JS Code:

```
$('#product-table').DataTable({
    stateSave: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "/api/stock/products",
        type: "POST",
        "Columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "description" },
            { "data": "current_stock" },
            { "data": "cost_price" },
            { "data": "retail_price" }
        ]
    },
});
```

Json data Being Returned:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "product 1",
      "description": "test product",
      "current_stock": "200",
      "cost_price": "2000",
      "retail_price": "2500"
    }
  ]
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="product-table" width="100%" class="table table-hover">
       <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Current Stock</th>
                <th>Cost Price</th>
                <th>Retail price</th>
            </tr>
       </thead>
</table>
```

The ajax call is being sent through and returns data but as soon as the page loads DataTable throws the following error:

> DataTables warning: table id=product-table - Requested unknown
>   parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this
>   error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That JS Doesn't look right, try this instead:

```
$('#product-table').DataTable({
    "stateSave": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/api/stock/products",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    "columns": [{
        "data": "name"
    }, {
        "data": "description"
    }, {
        "data": "current_stock"
    }, {
        "data": "cost_price"
    }, {
        "data": "retail_price"
    }]
});
```